# Get Only First Parent of each child

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get direct parent (if exists also not grand parents) of each child element in order, so far I have tried this function:

```
$child_id  = 15;
$query = "SELECT * FROM family WHERE parent_id < $child_id ORDER By parent_id DESC LIMIT 0,7";
$res        =   mysql_query($query);
while($obj = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $results[]  =   $obj;
}

$fetchedResults =   fetchParentsById($results, $child_id);

function fetchParentsById($results, $id, $parentfound = false, $parents= array())
{
    foreach($results as $row)
    {
        if((!$parentfound && $row['parent_id'] == $id) || $row['child_id'] == $id && $row['parent_id'] > 0)
        {
            $rowdata = array();
            foreach($row as $k => $v)
                        {
                $rowdata[$k] = $v;
                        }
            $parents[] = $rowdata;
            if($row['child_id'] == $id)
                        {
                $parents= array_merge($parents, fetchParentsById($results, $row['parent_id'], true));
                        }
        }
    }
    return $parents;
}
```

Now, I get all the parents but I want to get parents till the desired level from bottom up, e.g. I have 15 records, if I give child_id=15 and level = 4, then it should get me (1) parent of 15 (2) parent of 14 (3) parent of 13 (4) parent of 12 and should not proceed.

Iow, I just have to limit the number to fetch the parents to the desired level.

Any better solution, or where am I mistaking?

**Table Structure :**

```
id | parent_id | child_id
```

Comment: Can you provide an outline of the table structure?

Comment: Only three columns (id, parent_id, child_id)

Comment: .. direct parents are taken with just a query as ...
SELECT * FROM family WHERE child_id = $child_id
...
And then attach your data from other tables using each row parent_Id..
I don't understand why you need such PHP functions for detecting them ?

Comment: mysql_ should not be used - please google the manual. Deprecated functions

Comment: actually i want to get the direct parents to limited numbers, and not beyond that, so, i had to use this function... it might not be good idea.. That is why i am asking for a better solution if other than this, to achieve the desired results...

Comment: @Trent It has nothing to do with mysql. He needs a logic

Comment: @CodeHunter It's a responsible thing to do to inform people when they are using functions that are not guaranteed to be supported for long...

Comment: @COd3Eat3R - read this article http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ - you need a primer in hierarchical data; as your above query is so highly over engineered, it's actually quite hard to see what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i was thinking your table structure is wacky. Until i realized that its a cross-table and `id` is not what `parent_id` or `child_id` refer to.

Assuming there is only one parent per child, i would advise structuring your table simpler:

```
| id | parent_id |
```

And use `NULL` for `parent_id` to indicate an `id` has no parent. The query would simply be

```
SELECT * FROM family WHERE parent_id = NULL
```

---

Or if the data has fixed `id`'s that may or may not appear in the data, use a query like

```
SELECT * FROM family WHERE parent_id <> (SELECT id FROM family GROUP BY id)
```

to find any `parent_id` that is not listed in the table as `id`. But that would assume the data is incomplete.. which it should never be unless you dont have to trust your data.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion yes it seems that will do!

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at Closure Sets.

Read from slide 48 on for a few ways of working with Parent / Child data.

http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back

You'll need to restructure your data - whether it's worth it (or not) depends on the volume of queries you expect.

Comment: thank you for your reply, yes I think that would be necessary!